# Invalid Icon I can not find which icon is missing or invalid

Tags: firebase, flutter, icons

I have an error message..  Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource grocery could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null))

The issue is that I can not find which asset or icon is missing.

The error is appearing when running flutterLocal NotificationPlugin.initialize

[image]

The app freeze after signing in.

All the files are upto date.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to follow these steps.

1. Add the icon to drawable and mipmap folders which you want to show in the notification bar.
   [image]
2. Then add this in the manifest file inside <application tag.

   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
3. Finally initialize the [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

   ```
    Future<void> showNotification(String title, String subtitle, String action) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description', style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText,
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker', icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher");
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, '$title', '$subtitle', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: action);}
   ```

Call the function where you configure the receiver of the notification.

Answer (score 7):

error is showing because you have not added the icon for notification. Notification icon can be you app icon itself or any other icon you want to show in notification.

To add icon go to

```
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/
```

and copy your app icon (it would be in png format) then paste icon here

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable/
```

[drawable file](https://github.com/Amit506/Alarm_app/tree/main/android/app/src/main/res/drawable)

Then copy your icon folder name and initialize into initializationSettings.

Note: only name of file like  ic_launcher(folder name ic_launcher.png).

```
final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettings =
AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettings),
     onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload' + payload);
 }
});
```

[github repo](https://github.com/Amit506/Alarm_app/blob/main/lib/main.dart) refer my code for more or can ask if still find difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick fix:
Add this to AndroidNotificationDetails

`icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'`

This will solve the issue.